# Spree Commerce user password to Magento 1.8 migration?

Tags: spree, magento-1.8

I'm trying to migrate for Spree Commerce to Magento 1.8 and I have a problem with user passwords. Can I get any NFO from you guys how I can achieve this goal. How passwords are encrypted (bCrypt, MD5 etc.)? Is it possible to decrypt it with PHP and save it while migrating Spree user data to Magento.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The most popular user management extension for Spree is spree_auth_devise, which is build on the popular Devise project.  By default, Devise uses bcrypt to digest passwords.  It is not possibly to decrypt a digested password.

If you with to maintain user accounts during your migration, you will have to modify Magento to use the same algorithm that devise uses to verify passwords.

For more information you should look at the Devise source:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb

Comment: Thx. I will check it out. Regardless it's a shame that there is no turning back :p